# updating a record with entity framework not working

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

This is my code:

```
...
Domain.Box updatedBox = entities.Boxes.FirstOrDefault(TextBoxBoxID.Text);
updatedBox = getBoxInfo();
entities.SaveChanges();

private Domain.Box getBoxInfo()
    {
        Domain.Box retBox = new Domain.Box();
        retBox.BoxID = TextBoxBoxID.Text;
        retBox.LocationID = Convert.ToDecimal(TextBoxLocationID.Text);
        retBox.Positions = Convert.ToByte(TextBoxPositions.Text);            
        retBox.DiseaseID = RadComboBoxDisease.SelectedValue;
        retBox.SampleTypeID = RadComboBoxSampleType.SelectedValue;
        retBox.TubeTypeId = RadComboBoxTubeTypeID.SelectedValue;

        return retBox;
    }
```

The code compiles and executes fine, but the database does not changes, this is, all the information is exactly the same as it was before the update. Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do here. Retrieve a Domain.Box object and then set its value to a new object?

Comment: webyac, you are overwriting a _reference_. Nothing of the FirstOrDefault box remains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to insert a new Domain.Box object, you should do it like this:

```
entities.Boxes.AddObject(getBoxInfo());
entities.SaveChanges();
```

There is no need to create the `updatedBox` object because you're just overwriting it. If I understand you're requirements, you want to perform an insert, not an update.

If I'm incorrect and you're trying to update certain properties of the `updatedBox` object, then just pass a reference to the object and update it's properties:

```
Domain.Box updatedBox = entities.Boxes.FirstOrDefault(TextBoxBoxID.Text);
getBoxInfo(ref updatedBox);
entities.SaveChanges();

private void getBoxInfo(ref Domain.Box retBox)
{
    retBox.BoxID = TextBoxBoxID.Text;
    ...
}

entities.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Thank you, I was missing indeed the reference to the ET object

Answer (score 0):

I'd try it this way:

```
Domain.Box updatedBox = entities.Boxes.FirstOrDefault(TextBoxBoxID.Text);
getBoxInfo(updatedBox);
entities.SaveChanges();

private void getBoxInfo(Domain.Box retBox)
    {
        retBox.LocationID = Convert.ToDecimal(TextBoxLocationID.Text);
        retBox.Positions = Convert.ToByte(TextBoxPositions.Text);            
        retBox.DiseaseID = RadComboBoxDisease.SelectedValue;
        retBox.SampleTypeID = RadComboBoxSampleType.SelectedValue;
        retBox.TubeTypeId = RadComboBoxTubeTypeID.SelectedValue;
    }
```

Comment: I don't think you need to pass by reference unless Domain.Box is a value type.

Comment: And BoxId probably should _not_ be changed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do this:

```
Domain.Box updatedBox = entities.Boxes.FirstOrDefault(TextBoxBoxID.Text);
UpdateBoxInfo(updatedBox);
entities.SaveChanges();

private void UpdateBoxInfo(Domain.Box theBox)
    {
        theBox.BoxID = TextBoxBoxID.Text;
        theBox.LocationID = Convert.ToDecimal(TextBoxLocationID.Text);
        theBox.Positions = Convert.ToByte(TextBoxPositions.Text);            
        theBox.DiseaseID = RadComboBoxDisease.SelectedValue;
        theBox.SampleTypeID = RadComboBoxSampleType.SelectedValue;
        theBox.TubeTypeId = RadComboBoxTubeTypeID.SelectedValue;
    }
```